# Visual Studio 2015 Hot Towel Angular

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, hottowel

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 RC1.  I am trying to install the Hot Towel Angular Package.  When I install it I receive the following messages in the output window:

> Installing NuGet package HotTowel.Angular.2.3.3. Successfully
>   installed 'HotTowel.Angular.2.3.3' to ValueInvestingMentor.Web.
>   ========== Finished ========== Restoring packages for C:\Users\kruerj\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ValueInvestingMentor\src\ValueInvestingMentor.Web\project.json
>   Writing lock file C:\Users\kruerj\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ValueInvestingMentor\src\ValueInvestingMentor.Web\project.lock.json
>   Restore complete, 1741ms elapsed

When I look at my project.json file it looks like this:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "HotTowel.Angular": "2.3.3"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

However, no files are installed in my project.

I Have tried it with an "Empty" Web Application project and also with a "Web API" and an "MVC" project. None of them are successful.

What am I doing wrong?

I have used it in Visual Studio 2012 without any problems at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered similar issue when I am installing the HotTowel angular through Nuget. Here's what I have done in order to make the HotTowel angular application work with VS2015 RC

- Empty WebApplication with WebApi support Installed
- HotTowel.Angular.2.3.3 for SPA from Nuget

While installing the above package, some of the scripts are not being copied automatically. So, added them manually. List of those files are

- angular-route.js
- angular-animate.js
- angular-sanitize.js

You can get the external libraries through google very easily. Hope it will resolve your issue.